# Although ignored globally, git lists a new file on new repository

Tags: git, gitignore

The file `[repository-name].sublime-workspace` is listed on `git status` as new although it has been ignored via the global ignore file.

**.gitignore_global** (located in `C:\Users\[User]\`)

```
*.sublime-workspace
```

**.gitconfig** (located in `C:\Users\[User]\`)

```
[core]
    excludefile = c:/Users/[User]/.gitignore_global
```

**Checking status**

```bash
$ git status
On branch gh-pages
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/gh-pages'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   [repository-name].sublime-workspace
```

The global ignore file is working on several projects and I am aware of the fact, that already tracked files will continue to be tracked.

However, this is a new repository (both locally and remotely). I don't understand, why it is listing the file there. How comes? Please note: I don't want to list this file in the project-specific `.gitignore`. It's not specific to the project and I want it to be ignored in general.

The file in question was copied to the directory and appeared on `git status`. It was not staged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh no! It’s right there.

```
[core]
    excludefile = c:/Users/[User]/.gitignore_global
```

The smallest issues cause the biggest troubles. A missing letter.

```
[core]
    excludesfile = c:/Users/[User]/.gitignore_global
```

The freakin’ global ignore did not work at all!

Comment: During my tests here I did the same mistake and I didn't notice. But this does not explain you the file got staged. In your question the git status output shows the file being staged.

Comment: It shows the file as _new_. It was not added and committed. Right after fixing the typo and typing `git status`, it vanished. Magic!

Comment: When git-status is saying `Changes to be committed:` (as it does in your question) it means it was already staged hence my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the file has been staged before it has been ignored by any .gitignore-file.

IOW: someone did

```
git add .sublime-workspace
```

before or

```
git add -f .sublime-workspace
```

after it has been added to a .gitignore-file.

Comment: That is not the case. I'm working on an entirely new repository add didn't to `git add . --all`. I already stated that in my question. Basically, I copied the file over and typed `git status` and there it was.

Comment: I create a new folder. I copy `file.sublime-workspace` there. I cd there and do `git init && git status` and it's listed.

Comment: Strange things are happening.

Comment: I could swear that I have seen somewhere sublime dot workspace here instead of sublime dash workspace...

Comment: Also check the git template on your system. When git-init is run it copies hooks and other stuff. Maybe there is something which forces a git add of *.sublime-workspace - my last idea.

Comment: `file.sublime.workspace` was a typo in my previous comments. The extension is `.sublime-workspace`. My template directory looks clean as well.